# Potential energy in Schrödinger equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

In the Schrödinger equation what does potential
energy $V$ mean?

In harmonic oscillation, it is the potential energy of the particle itself.
However, in a potential well, it
looks like the potential is an external energy environment.

What does $V(x)$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

The potential (to be more precise, the gradient of the potential) represents the force acting on a particle as a consequence of its position. In solid state physics, for example, it might be used to represent the electromagnetic forces acting on an electron. For most real life applications, the Schrödinger equation can't be solved analytically- you have to use numerical techniques to find solutions. Even then, it is very difficult to solve the equations by explicitly accounting for all the individual particle in the system being considered, so instead physicists use simpler models. A common technique is to adopt a 'one-electron' model of a solid, in which you solve the Schrodinger equation for a single electron, taking into account its interactions with all the other electrons and ions in the solid by replacing them with a background potential that simulates their effects.